# Можно ли создать поле класса только для чтения?

Tags: c++, классы

Можно ли поле класса объявить так, что бы можно было узнать его значение просто через точку но при этом нельзя было изменить. Выглядеть должно как то так:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    onlyread int i;
    MyClass() {
        i = 0;
    }
    void foo() {
        i = 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass test;
    std::cout << test.i << std::endl;//корректно, мы просто получаем значение переменной i
    test.i = 2;//некорректно, нельзя внешне изменить значение переменной 
               //объявленной с ключевым словом onlyread
    test.foo();//корректно, методы класса могут менять значение переменной i
}
```

Сейчас же приходится писать так:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    int i;
public:
    MyClass() {
        i = 0;
    }
    void foo() {
        i = 2;
    }
    const int geti(){
        return i;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass test;
    std::cout << test.geti() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Наверняка можно, используя `const` и приведения типа в методах класса для изменения значения. **Но зачем?** (впрочем, кажется [EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) уже ответил на такой риторический вопрос)

Comment: А чем подход с getter-ом плох?

Comment: В других язвказ, например с#, можно. Но в плюсах подход с get_*** и set_*** общепринят и считается нормальным.

Comment: @zenden2k Его писать надо

Comment: Так, как вы хотите, в C++ не пишут. Возможно ниже вам предложат какое-то решение с помощью костылей и велосипедов, но такое лучше не использовать для нормального аккуратного программирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, нельзя. Но если очень хочется вызывать без геттера, то можно выставить наружу ссылку (при этом будет оверхед):

```
class MyClass
{
private: int m_i;
public: int const & i;
public: MyClass(void): m_i{}, i{m_i} {}
public: void foo() { m_i = 2; }
};
```

А геттер по-хорошему должен возвращать ссылку и сам иметь const-квалификатор. Использование const-квалификатора для встроенных типов, возвращаемых из функции, является ошибкой:

```
int const & geti() const
```

Comment: *"Использование const-квалификатора для встроенных типов, возвращаемых из функции, является ошибкой:"* Насколько я понимаю, `const` здесь ничего не делает. GCC выдает об этом варнинг.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну вот

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
protected: 
    int j = 0;
};

class MyClass : protected Base {
public:
    const int& i;
    MyClass() : i(Base::j) {}   
    void foo() {
        Base::j = 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass test;
    std::cout << test.i << std::endl;
    //test.i = 2;//ошибка: нельзя изменить значение переменной 
                 //через константную ссыльку    
    test.foo(); 
    std::cout << test.i;
    return 0;
}
```